# Vuejs Console Errors after changing hostname in config

Tags: webpack, vue.js

Vuejs Newbie here. I'm creating a simple VueJs application using vue cli 3 and changed the hostname from localhost to pc555 in vue.config.js. Something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    host: "pc555",
  }
};
```

The application loads fine but there are a lot of console errors.
[image: console errors]

I am guessing this is related to the hot reload and since I changed the hostname to pc555, it's not able to find localhost. How do I make these urls go to http://pc555:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1533154684963 instead of http://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1533154684963?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you change the host when initializing SockJS? Ex: `new SockJS('http://localhost:8080');` to `new SockJS('http://pc555:8080')`

Comment: No. I changed it before starting the web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to change the devServer.public setting to inform webpack that you want to use that host name for HMR look ups. https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuejs-console-errors-after-changing-host-name/39997/2